# What is the significant difference between the Germanic language group and the Romance group?

Tags: germanic-languages, romance-languages

People classify English, German and Dutch into Germanic language group and French, Spanish, Italian into the Romance language family. I learned English and the others before, but I still don't understand why they classify this way, because of the differences of sentence, grammar, structure or their culture in history?

Comment: This is a great question, but as worded it's not really about learning languages. It's more about the history and/or linguistic charactaristics of Language. As such, it's probably a better fit for [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), but I'm sure it's currently too simple for their taste. I suggest starting with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_family), and if you still have questions, followup there.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between the Germanic languages and the Latin (and Celtic) languages is [Grimm's Law](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/IE_Main5_Grimm.html), which describes a set of sound changes that map Germanic words to their Latin and Celtic cognates. The Germanic sounds were shifted from their Proto-Centum or Proto-Indo-European forms, while the Latin and Celtic sounds either did not change or were changed in some other way (out of scope of this answer).

For example, Germanic *th* corresponds to Latin *t*, and Germanic *t* corresponds to Latin *d*, so

- English *t*oo*th* corresponds to Spanish *d*ien*t*e.
- English *th*ree corresponds to French *t*rois.

Germanic *h* corresponds to Latin *c*, so

- German *h*und and English *h*ound correspond to Classical Latin *c*anis.
- German *h*unnert and English *h*undred correspond to Classical Latin *c*entum.

Germanic *f* corresponds to Latin *p*, so,

- English *f*ish corresponds to Spanish *p*ez.
- English *f*oo*t* corresponds to French *p*ie*d* (also includes the *t* - *d* difference mentioned earlier!).
- English *f*a*th*er corresponds to Classical Latin *p*a*t*er (also includes the *th* - *t* mentioned earlier!).

Some Germanic languages, for example German and Swedish (but not English or Icelandic), have undergone an additional *th* to *d* shift. High German has undergone even more. C.f. the High German Sound Shift.

This law is very useful for learning a language in one of the families if you already know a language in the other family. For example, if you know English, you can more easily learn Spanish vocabulary by noting the correspondences.

You can even use this law to map fancy Latin-derived terms in English to their common Germanic forms in English. For example, a "cardiac" arrest can be interpreted as a "heartiac" arrest (using *c* -> *h* and *d* -> *t*), which is what it is.