# What strategies there are for learning a Romance language when I already know a Germanic language?

Tags: learning-methods, germanic-languages, romance-languages

In a comment on another question, [What is the difference between Germanic and Romance languages?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4390/3595), Robert Columbia wrote:

> There are actually known strategies for learning a language from one of those families if you know one in the other family (E.g. learning Italian if you speak Swedish).

I know English, Norwegian, Danish, and some Swedish (as well as the finno-ugric Finnish). I am trying to slowly learn French. This is not really a priority, but rather a slow experiment in seeing if my language skills will improve with modest, but regular, practice.

What are the known strategies implied in the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique I was speaking of is known as Grimm's Law.

From another [answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2733/2167) I posted a while back:

> The main difference between the Germanic languages and the Latin (and Celtic) languages is [Grimm's Law](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/IE_Main5_Grimm.html), which describes a set of sound changes that map Germanic words to their Latin and Celtic cognates. The Germanic sounds were shifted from their Proto-Centum or Proto-Indo-European forms, while the Latin and Celtic sounds either did not change or were changed in some other way (out of scope of this answer).
>
> ...
>
> English tooth corresponds to Spanish diente.
>
> English three corresponds to French trois.
>
> ...
>
> German hund and English hound correspond to Classical Latin canis.
>
> ...
>
> English fish corresponds to Spanish pez.
>
> English foot corresponds to French pied

See my answer linked above for more examples (and a better explanation of them), and also see the original article I linked to for an in-depth look at the law.

In your case, you should note that additional sound shifts have occurred in French. For example, the word for "dog" is *chien*, which has undergone a sound shift from Latin hard-c to a soft "sh". Similarly, French "chaud" corresponds to English "hot" - the French "ch" comes from the Latin "c" (with the "d" remaining unchanged), and the English "h" and "t" come through Grimm's Law.